# Testing v-slot in validation observer

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I got into a scenario where I need to check if v-slot contain 'handleSubmit' and 'invalid' . Using jest to write the test cases

```html
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ handleSubmit , invalid }">
   <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(submit)">
         .....
         .....
   </form>
</ValidationObserver>
```

*"vue": "^2.6.10",
 "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
 "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.1.2",*

```js
Vue.component("ValidationObserver",ValidationObserver)
describe("testing v-slot ,() =>{
test('testing v-slot',() =>{
const wrapper = mount(ComponentName)
expect(wrapper.find(ValidationObserver).______) // not able to fetch v-slot values tried many ways using attributes() method , vm etc.
})
})
```

Any idea regarding this?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. I think it's cleaner to use `shallowMount` and mock the dependencies via some sort of DI mechanism, but unfortunately, the examples and tests provided in vee-validate all use `mount` and depend on the component code being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem as well. As far as I know stubbing the `ValidationObserver` and the `ValidationProvider` with the actual component works pretty well.

Example:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(ComponentName, {
  stubs: {
    ValidationObserver,
    ValidationProvider,
  },
})
```